# autofs not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: init.d, automount

Hi I am trying to automount remote file system using autofs. For this I installed autofs

```
% sudo apt-get install cifs-utils autofs
```

Then I edited /etc/auto.master to have the following line:

```
/ufs   /etc/auto.ufs
```

Then I created a file `/etc/auto.ufs` and edited it with the following line:

```
cad -rw,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 fiji.csl.cornell.edu:/usr/local/cad
```

Then I restarted autofs using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/autofs restart
```

and I got following message:

- Stopping automount...                                                                                                                        [ OK ]
- Starting automount...
                                                                                                                       /usr/sbin/automount: program is already running.
                                                                                                                                        [ OK ]

But still when I try to do `ls` in the `/ufs` folder it does not show anything. Can somebody tell what could be the issue?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; general software support questions are off-topic. This would fit better on SuperUser.

Comment: Did you check that `automount: files` exist in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? Did you verify that automount was indeed restarted. It seems it wasn't. Did you check any messages logged in `/var/log/messages` that may be relevant to `autofs`? Did you verify that your host is allowed to mount the remote filesystem?

Comment: I didn't have auatomount: files in /etc/nsswitch.conf but now have added it, but still its not working. There is no /var/log/messages file. How do I check that the host is allowed to mount remote file system or not?